# Add Icon and App name and Bundle ID to Broadcast Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, replaykit, rpbroadcastsamplehandler

[image]I have one Broad cast I want to add UIImage as Icon and add Name for Showing I find this code but How can I use it

here is code I found it but how can I add the icon and app name ?

```
[func loadBroadcastingApplicationInfo(completion handler: @escaping (String, String, UIImage?) -> Void)][1]
```

My be it is use full  something like this

```
 extensionContext?.loadBroadcastingApplicationInfo (completion: {  
            (bundleID, displayName, appIcon) in
```

but I don't know how to use it.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
        }

let broadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: btnRS.frame.width, height: btnRS.frame.height))
    broadcastPickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let button = broadcastPickerView.subviews.first as? UIButton {
        button.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.white

    }


    btnRS.addSubview(broadcastPickerView)
    broadcastPickerView.tintColor = .yellow
    broadcastPickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    broadcastPickerView.showsMicrophoneButton = true

    btnRS.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)


}
```

I used somthinglike this

```
   extensionContext?.loadBroadcastingApplicationInfo (completion: {  
            (bundleID, displayName, appIcon) in  
            if let icon = appIcon {  


            }  
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                if (displayName != "") {  

                }  


            }  

        })
```

Comment: Where you are calling extensionContext?.loadBroadcastingApplicationInfo this method?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I can calling this method in viewDidLoad but how can I add the Icon and App name , if you know please adding the code

Comment: Show ur code, How did u tried.?

Comment: How can u add ExtensionContext in ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 updated the codes and question  but how can change the app name and add icon please check it

Comment: extensionContext?.loadBroadcastingApplicationInfo, Where you are trying to Call this? In, ur viewController or extensionHandler or ExtensionHandlerUI ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 in my view controller

Comment: @McDonal_11 I don't use Extension Broadcast

Comment: You are not adding any broadcast extension. So that Only, default Camera Roll is visible, if u add some extension, you can achieve.

Comment: @McDonal_11 but I don't have a icon for Camera Roll too ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 it is not normal

Comment: @McDonal_11 can you write the code for add because in extension too we don't have assist for Icon